# count and display vowels in a string using array methods java

Tags: java, arrays, methods, char

I have been searching  for the solution for a while here , but I couldn't manage to find the needed solution , the one I'm asked to do... 
So I need to get a string from a user and count and display all Capital and Lower case vowels in a string.
Here is a required output:

```
Enter a string:
IAMHERE
a  : occured 0 
e  : occured 0 
i  : occured 0 
o  : occured 0 
u  : occured 0 
A  : occured 1 
O  : occured 0 
U  : occured 0
I  : occured 1
E  : occured 2
```

Here is what I have done so far:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class CountVowels {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter a string:");
        String input = sc.next();
        char[] chars = createArray(input);
        countLet(chars);
    }

    static char[] createArray(String str) {
        char[] chars = new char[str.length()];
        for (int i = 0; i < chars.length; i++) {
            chars[i] = str.charAt(i);
        }
        return chars;
    }

    static void countLet(char[] chars) {
        char[] vowels = {'a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u', 'A', 'O', 'U', 'I', 'E'};
        int numberOfVowels = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < chars.length; i++) {
            if (chars[i] == vowels[i]) {
                numberOfVowels++;
            }
            System.out.println(vowels[i] + "  : occured " + numberOfVowels + " ");
        }
    }
}
```

I know where the problem comes from ---> countLet
cuz I am comparing all chars in succession with vowels...for example the first letter of chars is 'I' but the first letter of vowels is 'a' , it is obvious that they aren't equal, what's more the output of my code doesn't compare 'I' and 'E' letters since the input is smaller than the vowels.length...

The output of the latter code:

```
Enter a string:
IAMHERE
a  : occured 0 
e  : occured 0 
i  : occured 0 
o  : occured 0 
u  : occured 0 
A  : occured 0 
O  : occured 0
```

So what can I do ?!

Comment: you have to iterate over the vowels and inside this loop, count how many times the current vowel occurs. at the end of the vowel loop print out the number of times

Answer (score 2):

The problem occurs as you are comparing `chars[i]` to `vowels[i]`. Since you are incrementing `i` the program isn't having the desired output.

For example, the string: `Hello`:

> H is checked against only 'a'
>
> e is checked against only 'e'
>
> l is checked against only 'i'
>   etc.

This also means if the length of the string is greater than `vowels.length` then you would get an IndexOutOfBounds exception.

The code you need to check if each letter was a vowel:

```java
for (char c : input) { // Loop through each character in the string
    for (char v : vowels) { // Loop through each vowel
        if (c == v) { // The letter is a vowel
           numberOfVowels++;
           break; // The letter cannot be another vowel too, so break out of the inner loop
        }
    }
}
```

You could then modify this and change vowels to a `Map<Character, Integer>` in order to track how many times each vowel has been seen

Comment: @Lino yep forgot it was a primitive

Comment: The for loops should be swapped, else you can't really print the output OP want to have